# tkinter how to automatically scroll and move

Tags: tkinter, geometry, scrollview, move

I am trying to create the game "Geometry Dash" with Tkinter. But I dont know how to scroll automatically with my charakter(that you can see him all time).And how the charakter can move evenly to the side.

[image]

Comment: That depends on how you create the game. Are you using a canvas? A text widget? Something else? Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: A canvas scrollbar has a set() function, see the docs at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm